# Automapper - Ensure Sub Properties are different Instances from Source and are created using IOC

Tags: c#, automapper, unity-container, caliburn.micro

I am currently working on a scenario where I would need the Automapper to use IOC to create new instances. Additionally, I would need to register the mapping for Automapper only when the requirement rises (so i am not using Profile Files). In order the achieve the same, I have done the following.

```
var cfg = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type =>
            {
                return CreateInstanceUsingIOC(type);
            });

cfg.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>()
    .ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg);
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var model1UsingIoC = CreateModel1UsingIoC();
model1UsingIoC.MyProfile = new Person();
model1UsingIoC.MyProfile.FirstName = "New First Name";
model1UsingIoC.MyProfile.LastName = "New Last Name";
model1UsingIoC.CommonProperty = "This wont be copied";
var model2b = mapper.Map<Model2>(model1UsingIoC);
```

This works as desired, however, problem lies with the inner property Model1.MyProfile. The instance of MyProfile in Source and Destination looks to be the same.

```
ReferenceEquals(model2b.MyProfile,model1UsingIoC.MyProfile) // True
```

In addition, I would like to create each of the User Defined sub properties using IoC. For the purpose, I added modified the ConstructServicesUsing statement as

```
 cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type =>
            {
                var instance = CreateInstance(type);
                return ReassignProperties(instance);
            });
```

Where ReassignProperties is defined as

```
public static object ReassignProperties(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return null;
    Type objType = obj.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        // Check if its a collection
        if (property.IsEnumerable())
        {
            if (property.GetValue(obj, null) is IEnumerable elems)
            {
                foreach (var item in elems)
                {
                    ReassignProperties(item);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If it is User Defined Type, Recursively loop again
            if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly)
            {
                var newValue = CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
                property.SetValue(obj, newValue);
                var value = property.GetValue(obj);
                ReassignProperties(value);
            }
            else
            {
                var propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
                Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name} = {propValue}");

            }

        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

But as one could assume, that didn't help either and while mapping, the same instance is being copied over for subproperties. Could someone guide me on how to ensure a new instance is created for user defined sub properties when using Automapper (ie, new instance are created and values are copied over unless the type is primitive type) ?

**Update 001**

As suggested by Lucian, i tried creating a custom mapper as follows and add it to Mapping Registery.

```
public class NewInstanceMapper : IObjectMapper
{
    public bool IsMatch(TypePair context) => true;


    public static object CreateInstance(Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            var methodInfo = typeof(IoC).GetMethod(nameof(IoC.Get), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
            var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            return genericMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { null });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
    }

    public Expression MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap, PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression, Expression contextExpression)
    {
        return Expression.Call(this.GetType(), nameof(CreateInstance), null, Expression.Constant(destExpression.Type));
    }
}
```

And added it to MappingRegistery using

```
var cfg = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
cfg.Mappers.Insert(0,new NewInstanceMapper());
```

But, as one could guess, this created new instance, but didn't copy the value

**Additional Notes**
Please note what I would like to achieve would be

- a) Each property values are copied over to destination based on naming conventions
- b) Each destination property (exception for string) are new instance
  each created using IoC, and are not the same instances of source property
- c) Point b includes nested properties, collections (each element in collection needs to be created using ioc and sub property values values copied over)

Comment: You can remove the default `AssignableMapper` and create your own that does what you want. Or perhaps use another mapper altogether. The defaults are there for a reason.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Default AssignableMapper - am slightly lost there. Do you mean implementing a Custom IMapper ?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Out of curiousity, could we do something with .ForMember ?

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways, but I would start at the source. You'll have to do a little research.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I tried adding a Custom Mapper as you had mentioned, but that seem to be helping. I have updating the OP with my attempted code. Could you please check if this is how you meant it ? I could be wrong due to my inability to pick your clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a map for your `Person` class to itself will ensure that instances are deep copied when mapped:

`cfg.CreateMap<Person, Person>();`

If any of your sub-properties are also reference types that need to be deep copied, you can follow the same strategy and define self-maps for them too.

Comment: If the person is a child property, this would result in Person to be copied over destination's child property (Same Instance). Or rather `ReferenceEquals(Source.Person,Destination.Person)` would be true. This is what I need to avoid. I would require only the values to be copied over - both child properties should be the same instance. Also, FYI, for the Same Type, you do not need to create the Map.

Comment: @ AnuViswan if you create a map as per the answer the person instance won’t be the same as source. A new instance will be created. If you also call `ConstructUsingServiceLocator` the new instance will be resolved using DI. I think this suits what you want. Without the same type map, `AssignableMapper` just copies the source instance over to destination.

Comment: @Dean I am extremely sorry that I didn't try out your answer. My apologies, I "thought" that won't work. Am extremely sorry.

Comment: @Weichch, Thanks a lot for pointing it. Your explanation made it all clear

Comment: @Dean unfortunately, I could award the bounty only in another 5 hours due to restriction in SO, but surely will do it at that time. Thanks a lot

Comment: No worries @AnuViswan - I'm glad it worked in the end!